# Check if client is connected to Workflow Service

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I'd like to write a selfhosted .NET Workflow Service like this:

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hij20.png)

But how can I determine if the client is still alive? The InactivityTimeout of the WCF binding doesn't seems to trigger. I could write a Timeout function(measure the time between the last request an now). But this doesn't ensure that the client is disconnected and not only idle. Isn't there a common way in the .NET Framework?

Thank You.

Comment: Workflow Service is a WCF service, you don't connect to a WCF service per se. The client calls service methods and (usually) receives a response back. What do you mean by the client being *alive*?

Comment: @Jota The service instance is kept alive by the loop until ExitWf is called. So the client can call the functions multiple times in a radom order. But if the client e.g. crash ExitWF is never called and the instance will never be removed

Answer (score 0):

you run this service from somewhere and you have to run a server to get back response from the service. you can make a callback server by using this code:

```
 var host = new ServiceHost(serviceCallback, new Uri("localhost:8080"));
```

and then in the service you need to send information back to this address. so you can track the current status of your service dynamically in the caller client.